# How to serve files from express 4.0 public folder as formatted html and not files, based on extension? E.g. format JSON, show images

Tags: javascript, json, express, jpeg

Hey so anytime I place something in the "public" dir of my express directory, it automatically has a link on my webpage that I like. For example, going to https://website.com/image.jpg will allow me to download an image, and https://website.com/object.json will allow me to download a JSON file, without me having to do anything aside from place these files in my public folder. This is super convenient since I have another script that could be making a bunch of different things that I won't want to specify by name on my server every time I change something.

What I would like to do is modify this serve command so that when I want to retrieve an image, instead of automatically downloading it, it displays it in the browser. This should be as simple as adding an `<html> </html>` around anything in the public folder that has the .png file ending. Likewise, I would like to stringify any JSON file so that it comes out in a readable format (JSON.stringify(object,null,2));

Basically, I would like to be able to just put something in my public folder and automatically be able to access it in a desirable way based on its file extension. In these two cases the "desirable" way is not downloading the file, but displaying it in-browser in a human-friendly format.

Answer (score 0):

display of static files in nodejs is not a trivial behavior. you'd usually set a folder as static which becomes public and end url fragment is same as file name. Using Express with Nodejs, it looks like this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join('.', 'public')));
```

Because you don't like default implementation, you can rather parse the url manually, check if a file by that name exists, wrap it around appropriate html, and throw it as response.

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    fileName = req.url.substring('https://website.com/'.length);
    if(fs.existsSync('public/'+fileName){
        if(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1)=='jpg')
            res.send('<html><body><img src="public/'+fileName+'"></img></body></html>')
})
```

As you can see, all urls are checked for files. You can also use a router while placing all public files under some subdirectory like '/public'